# Carnet insurance for driving into Iran?

Tags: driving, motorcycles, iran

I'm thinking of driving my motorbike to Iran. I've heard you need a 500% Carnet de Passages en Douane (CPD) to get into Iran, which would cost ~ €10,000 → €15,000. However I don't have that kind of money, even if you do get it back when you leave the country (with your vehicle). I've heard that you can get CPD insurance, where an insurance company fronts the cash, and you pay them. I've heard quotes of 10% CPD insurance, which would cost €1,000 → €1,500, which is a bit much.

Does anyone have any experience driving to Iran and getting a CPD? Where can I get cheap CPD insurance?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "carnet insurance"? Are you talking about a [Carnet de Passage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnet_de_Passage)?

Comment: Yes, Carnet de Passage. I've updated the question

Comment: I think you have a typo - don't you mean "Carpet insurance for flying into Iran"?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm nope, no typo. I do mean carnet de passage insurance for driving into Iran

Comment: @RoryMcCann: It was an attempt at humour.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Ah OK. ☺ Poe's Law strikes again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[www.horizonsunlimited.com](http://www.horizonsunlimited.com) Is the best place to get information on motorcycle overlanding.
Answer I can give you is: it depends where you live. It's easiest to get the carnet in your own country so you're usually restricted by what's available there.
I can only speak for the UK, where I was able to get a carnet insurance for ~£1,300 for a £2,000 motorcycle (but the UK is notoriously expensive for carnets), though upon the safe return of the motorbike and carnet to the home country, I got a refund of about £700 of that.
You'll have to contact the carnet issuing companies in your country for a definitive answer.